# How to list query which used an index while selecting result in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, pg-stat-activity

I know that Postgres has some utility extensions that collect stats for statements and indexes.

I want to list queries which used particular index, whichselectsg the result. Is there a way to get that result set?

Comment: No, the database doesn't keep track of index usage per statement.